# python Spacy custom NER – how to prepare multi-words entities?

Tags: python-3.x, spacy, named-entity-recognition

:) Please help :)

I`m preparing custom Name Entity Recognition using Spacy (blank) model. I use only one entity: Brand (we can name it 'ORG' as Organisation). I have short texts with ORGs & have prepared data like this (but I can change it):

```
train_data = [ 
    (‘First text in string with Name I want’, {'entities': [(START, END, ‘ORG')]}),
    (‘Second text with Name and Name2’, {'entities': [(START, END, ‘ORG'), (START2, END2, ‘ORG')]})
 ]
```

START, END – are the start and end indexes of the brand name in text , of course.

This is working well, but...

**The problem I have is how to prepare entities for Brands that are made of 2 (or more) words.**
Lets say Brand Name is a full name of a company. How to prepare an entity?

Consider the tuple itself for a single text:

text = 'Third text with Brand Name'

company = 'Brand Name'

- Can I treat company as a one word?

```
(‘Third text with Brand Name', {“entities”: [(16, 26, 'ORG')]})
```

- Or 2 separated brands ‘Brand’ & ‘Name’ ? (will not be useful in my case while using :( the model later)

```
(‘Third text with Brand Name', {“entities”: [(16, 21, 'ORG'), (22, 26, 'ORG')]})
```

- Or I should use a different format of labeling eg. **BIO** ?
  So **Brand** will be **B-ORG** and **Name** will be **I-ORG** ?

  - IF so can I prepare it like this for Spacy:

```
(‘Third text with Brand Name', {“entities”: [(16, 21, 'B-ORG'), (22, 26, 'I-ORG')]})
```

- or should I change the format of **train_data** because I also need the ‘O’ from BIO?
  How? Like this? :

```
(‘Third text with Brand Name', {"entities": ["O", "O", "O", "B-ORG", "I-ORG"]})
```

**The question is on the format of the train_data for ‘Third text with Brand Name'  - how to label the entity**. If I have the format, I will handle the code. :)

The same question for 3 or more words entities. :)

Comment: My question is **how the description of the multi-word entity (multi-word company name here) in training_data should look like in Spacy** (https://spacy.io/) ? e.g. in the given example:

`text = 'Third text with Brand Name', 

company_entity_to_be_labeled = 'Brand Name' , 

train_data = [ 
  (‘Third text with Brand Name', {"entities": ????????? })
 ]`

I have given 4 possible solutions, but I don't know if any is good. I found only practical examples of single-word names. On the other hand, tagging like BIO has many descriptions but no practical examples for Spacy.

Comment: Your question is perfectly clear, I'm not sure what is up with that commenter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just provide the start and end offsets for the whole entity. You describe this as "treating it as one word", but the character offsets don't have any direct relation to tokenization - they won't affect tokenizer output.

You will get an error if the start and end of your entity don't match token boundaries, but it doesn't matter if the entity is one token or many.

I recommend you take a look at the [training data section](https://spacy.io/usage/training#training-data) in the spaCy docs. Your specific question isn't answered explicitly, but that's only because multi-token entries don't require special treatment. Examples include multi-token entities.

Regarding BIO tagging, for details on how to use it with spaCy you can see the docs for [`spacy convert`](https://spacy.io/api/cli#convert).

Comment: Thank you for your help :). Especially that lack of examples  come from ‘multi-token entries don't require special treatment.’ ← was something I didn't think about :). I suspected that maybe I was overthinking the subject :D, but I couldn't resist ;) !!

I can`t cast a vote yet (newbie reputation), but I have marked your answer as solving the problem.